# How to identify if an SKSpriteNode is in a specific 2D location? (Swift, SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm creating a chess game using SpriteKit. For this specific example I will use my setup for moving pawns.

I've mapped the default forward movement for a pawn. However I want to detect whether or not there is a sprite in each of the diagonal adjacent squares, so that I can code the option for either taking this piece or cancelling the move depending on the colour of the piece.

In short I'm in need of a method to identify if an SKSpriteNode is in a specific location, and subsequently return that sprite if there is one there. Thanks.

Comment: You could add collision bit masks and see if a collision occurred. You can also write s method that checks if there is a piece in any specific spot you want by checking the x and y coordinates of other pieces. If you could show your code that would help more.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not enough details so i fear it may get closed. But you may want to look at enumerateChildNodes(withName:) to cycle through your pieces. Maybe have a dictionary to store which square stores which piece. You could also check your piece positions by using spriteName.position. e.g. spriteName.position.x > 0 && spriteName.position.x <= 10 && spriteName.position.y > 0 && spriteName.position.y <= 10, that checks to see if the sprite is in the first square. These are just ideas to potentially look at.